# How to change "Listing 1. Caption" to "Figure 1. Caption"?

Tags: floats, listings, numbering, captions

I have a listing like so:

```
\lstset{language=Python,caption={Caption}}
\begin{lstlisting}
some Python code goes here
\end{lstlisting}
```

In the PDF this appears as `Listing 1. Caption`. How can I make it appear as `Figure 1. Caption`? It is worth mentioning that  mixing real figures and listings has to keep consistent figure numbering.

Comment: You should check next link that worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814714/how-to-change-title-in-listings

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's appropriate to use a little trick here: don't set the caption in the `lstlisting` environment, but enclose the listing in `figure` and use `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Hello World}
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=2]
  print "Hello World!"
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This way you can mix real figures and listings while keeping consistent figure numbering.

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly. I tried putting it in figures before but it didn't do any good because I didn't move the captions.

Comment: This worked for me but the figures only show when the \listoffigures command is added, is there a way not to add the list?

Comment: Can the Figure label below?