# Long caption in minipage not centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, minipage

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}\usepackage{genmpage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
                mycode;
        \end{lstlisting}
        \captionof{figure}{Short.}
    \end{minipage}

    \medskip

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
                mycode;
        \end{lstlisting}
        \captionof{figure}{Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

In the first example, the caption is aligned perfectly in the middle. However, on the second one it isn't aligned in the center at all. It looks like it's left justified despite having a \centering on it.

Edit:

Using figures to encapsulate lstlistings cause minipages to be out of order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{genmpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}


    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
        \captionof{figure}{Figure at \#1.}
    \end{minipage}


     \begin{figure}
        \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
            Figure at #2;
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
            Figure at #3;
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words.}
    \end{figure}



\end{document}
```

The use of minipages for pictures is derived from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54449/161008

The use of figures for listings is derived from here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19668/161008

Comment: Why are you squeezing the listing into a minipage at all?

Comment: I was following this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54449/161008

Comment: The `minipage` seems unnecessary there, however

Comment: New here to latex, my document might be all cases of ungodly mess.

Comment: While unnecessary, the `minipage` has the good side effect to suppress the  `outside box or environment` warning

Comment: If you put the only real figure also in a figure environment, their order should be ok again. That said: if you insist on using floating environments like `figure`, you should also give floating specifier, such as `\begin{figure}[htbp]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the caption package. If the caption is less than one line, it is centred, otherwise it is justified.

If you want all captions to be centred, you can modify the default behaviour with `justification=centering`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{genmpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Figure}

\begin{document}


    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption={Short},captionpos=b]
            mycode;
    \end{lstlisting}

  \medskip

    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption={Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words. Multiple Words.},captionpos=b]
            mycode;
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question, removing the listing from minipage causes issues for other minipages.

Comment: @HighMans As you can see in my answer, I would not encapsulate the listings in anything and use their own caption mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my edit. How do you go about making the numbering "Figure X" instead of "Listing X"?

Comment: @HighMans Please see my updated answer

Comment: I just noticed, yes -- it shows "Figure X", but it doesn't counting with the other figures. I can change the name to something that suits my document, but was hoping it'd keep the global counter.

Comment: @HighMans A dirty hack: `\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}
 \captionof{lstlisting}{content...}
 \end{figure}`